# protein predicting by modeller and python

Tags: python, matplotlib, bioinformatics, protein-database

i am trying to run a python script that is written by salilab as a tutorial for modeller software. there is a python file in this tutorial with this code:

```
import pylab
import modeller

def r_enumerate(seq):
    """Enumerate a sequence in reverse order"""
    # Note that we don't use reversed() since Python 2.3 doesn't have it
    num = len(seq) - 1
    while num >= 0:
        yield num, seq[num]
        num -= 1

def get_profile(profile_file, seq):
    """Read `profile_file` into a Python array, and add gaps corresponding to
       the alignment sequence `seq`."""
    # Read all non-comment and non-blank lines from the file:
    f = open(profile_file)
    vals = []
    for line in f:
        if not line.startswith('#') and len(line) > 10:
            spl = line.split()
            vals.append(float(spl[-1]))
    # Insert gaps into the profile corresponding to those in seq:
    for n, res in r_enumerate(seq.residues):
        for gap in range(res.get_leading_gaps()):
            vals.insert(n, None)
    # Add a gap at position '0', so that we effectively count from 1:
    vals.insert(0, None)
    return vals

e = modeller.environ()
a = modeller.alignment(e, file='TvLDH-1bdmA.ali')

template = get_profile('1bdmA.profile', a['1bdmA'])
model = get_profile('TvLDH.profile', a['TvLDH'])

# Plot the template and model profiles in the same plot for comparison:
pylab.figure(1, figsize=(10,6))
pylab.xlabel('Alignment position')
pylab.ylabel('DOPE per-residue score')
pylab.plot(model, color='red', linewidth=2, label='Model')
pylab.plot(template, color='green', linewidth=2, label='Template')
pylab.legend()
pylab.savefig('dope_profile.png', dpi=65)
```

when i try to run the program in cmd, i got an error :
No Module named pylab 
but i've alredy insstalled matplotlib, numpy and scipy and also when i run it in visual studio there is no problem. can anyone help me understand what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Your python path is probably messed up for command line. You most likely have multiple versions installed, and the default version for command line does not have pylab installed.

Please see ...
[How to add to the PYTHONPATH in Windows, so it finds my modules/packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-so-it-finds-my-modules-packages)